# PictureBox Error with Multi Treading

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have been having issues with the Winforms PictureBox. The code I have is too long to post so I will just describe the issue.

My Winform contans a TreeView, Picturebox and Button. When you click the Button, the Form creates roughly 10,000 Background Workers. Each worker creates a WebClient to download HTML and an Image from a website. This works great and if any errors occur the Worker will not return any information.

In the Work Completed Event I check if the Worker returned information. If it has, I create a new TreeNode and find the correct place to insert it into my TreeView. I then add an Entry into a Dictionary to contain the Workers Info.

In the AfterSelect Event I set the PictureBox image to null. Then I check the Dictionary for an entry. If I find one i set the PictureBox Image to be the Image File I have stored.

Everything works great and I can move through the Nodes and see the different Image's just fine. The problem comes at around the 25%-30% mark. For some reason around that time the PictureBox stops showing me the Image and just shows the Big Red X. I try going back to Images I just saw but it does not change.

This issue does not happen on a Certain Image either as I can just start the project again and pick up where I left off. Any thought would be very welcome.

Comment: Do check if you're leaking resources; 10k is always big and won't stand any leaking..

Comment: Hope you are not storing 10k `Bitmap` / `Image` objects.

Comment: Could the problem be that I am storing all the Images as Variables in Memory? The final goal is to store them in a DataBase.

Comment: Well, storing 10k images in memory certainly isn't helping.  Only store what you need, save the rest to disk and load as needed.

Comment: Probably storing them in memory as `byte[]` would not be a big problem (you have to check that), but for sure don't store `Bitmap` / `Image` objects because they consume GDI+ resources.

Comment: _I set the PictureBox Image to be the Image File I have stored._ yup, if only. You can watch the GDI resources in the Task manger!

Answer (score 1):

So @Ican Stoev was correct. Image files were causing my Project to eat up lots of System Memory. This was the case of the problem. I changed the project to only store the Byte Array data and Disposed of each Image before I changed it and the projects works great now.

Answer (score 0):

10k workers downloading stuff is alot wich is probably what's creating this error seeing as the picture box is getting the error image, instead of 10k test it with like 500.